# Div nest structure

Tags: css, html

I have met a problem that i don't know where is wrong. my code is here:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 #top{
  width:100%;
  height: 78%;
  background-color: #ccc;
 }

 #left{
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
 }
 #right{
  width:50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="top">
      <div id="left">
         <div id="inside">asd</div>
      </div>
     <div id="right"></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

if I add nothing to the "inside" div, then the layout would be alright , just like this:
[image]

but if i add any tag or even a few words in the "inside" dev .the layout would get wrong.
[image]

I'm new to HTML,so I don't know the problem,who can tell me why this happens? I've been driven crazy!!!help~~~~:(

Comment: +1 for presentation - code sample, images, specific question - nice.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2nRKw/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use float (see the other answers), but you don't have to if you don't want to.

```
#left, #right { vertical-align:top; }
```

will get you what you want.

---

Aside: You should add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your page. In which case, you'll also need to add

```
html, body { height: 100% }
```

to your CSS.

Comment: +1 Ha - this works too.  I was wondering if there was a way to keep `inline-block` around...

Answer (score 0):

You're having a problem with `block` and `inline`.  When the text appears, the browser puts the inside `div` into `block` display which ruins the `inline` styling.  I'm not sure if there's a neat way around that using `inline-block` - you'll have to use `float`, I reckon.

---

Here's the `float` solution applied to your markup:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 #top {
    width:100%;
    height: 78%;
    background-color: #ccc;
 }

 #left {
    background:green;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:45%;
 }

 #right {
    background:pink;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:45%;
    width:50%;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="top">
      <div id="left">
         <div id="inside">asdf</div>
      </div>

     <div id="right"></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Further, be careful of CSS `height`.  It's a headache waiting to happen.

Comment: It seems the only way I can do it's to use float, I still have a question about why I add display:inline-block to "inside", no thing happens?

Comment: I think it's because you have a `block` in an `inline`.  Things that are `inline` (or, apparently, `inline-block`) shouldn't have a `block` in them.  Block is top-level since it forces linebreaks and fills the width of the container. `inline` just sorta sits there.  So `block` in an `inline` is asking for trouble - and you got it. :)

Comment: you really help me a lot~ I think I should find some books about the css to know further things~thank you for your help:)

Comment: No problem, good luck.  If an answer here helped you, the community appreciates it if you mark it as "solved".  ;)  For CSS I'd recommend a hands-on approach, like this site: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/css-coding-with-style

Comment: Oh just FYI also you may have noticed I put CSS properties in alphabetical order.  Since they're always the same, alphabetical order is a good habit to get into since it helps you debug later.  Also, white space is your friend too - everyone will find your work easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 #right{
width:50%;
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
background-color: pink;
float:right;}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pXUCb/)

Comment: Note that display:inline-block is overridden by float:left, so you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

there is also  way to gain it by giving `float` to an element

```
#left {
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
 /* display: inline-block; */
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Note that `display:inline-block` is overridden by `float:left`, so you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue by adding a float attribute in css.

Find the updated html template below

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 #top{
  width:100%;
  height: 78%;
  background-color: #ccc;
 }

 #left{
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
float: left;
  background-color: green;
 }
 #right{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
float: left;
  background-color: pink;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="top">
      <div id="left">
         <div id="inside">test new</div>
      </div>
     <div id="right">test</div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand to you twitter bootstrap for the layout of your div. 
Using their css sheet.

```
<div id=top class=row-fluid>
 <div id=right class=span6><div>
 <div id=left class=span6><div>
</div>
```

The placement of block is way easier than with inline-block. All you need to get what you show in example is to add the background color. And float can easily become hard to handle.